# Define ColorFunction that constrains $0$ to be gray and uses full range on positive or negative values

Tags: color, plotting

I will produce a large number of `ListDensityPlot`s in which each entry can be positive or negative.  I'd like to color positive values in green, negative values in red, and the value of $0$ as  medium gray.

An off-the-shelf attempt at a solution is to use a `ColorFunction` such as `"RedGreenSplit"`, as here:

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i] + .4, {i, 0, 2, .4}, {j, 0, 2, .4}];

ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit"]
```

[image: RedGreenSplit ListDensityPlot]

There are three immediate problems, two fairly simple, the other hard (as far as I can see).

- The blending puts white in the middle of the range, while I seek gray (and thus blends from gray to green, and gray to red).
- The white is placed in the *middle* of the *range* of values; there is no guarantee that the value $0$ *must* correspond to gray.  Notice that for the function I used, there is an overall offset ($0.4$) but the coloring does not respect that.  (If I include `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, gray need not correspond to points having value $0$.)
- The maximum absolute value should be pure red or pure green, and the opposite color should be scaled the same.  Thus if the range is $[-1,2]$ then the colors should go from a *partial* red/gray, through gray, up to *full* green.  If instead the range is $[-6,3]$, then the colors should range between *full* red, through gray, up to *partial* green/gray.

Thus I want a color function that is `Piecewise`, as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75808), but somehow the ranges must be set to ensure the colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[myBlend]
myBlend[minmax_: {0, 1}, colors_: {Red, Gray, Green}] :=
 Blend[Thread[{{-Max@Abs@minmax, 0, Max@Abs@minmax}, colors}], #] &
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
array1 = RandomReal[{-.5, 1}, {11, 11}];
array2 = -array1;

Row[ListDensityPlot[#, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ImageSize -> 400,
    ColorFunction -> myBlend[MinMax@#], ColorFunctionScaling -> False,  
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"minmax : ", MinMax@#}]] & /@ {array1, array2}]
```

[image]

Comment: ...oh... even better.  ($\checkmark$)

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  (almost)

```
array = Table[
   RandomReal[{-.5, 1}],
   {i, -5, 5}, {j, -5, 5}];

mycf[z_] := Piecewise[
   {{Blend[{Gray, Red}, Abs[z]/Max[Abs[array]]], z <= 0},
    {Blend[{Gray, Green}, Abs[z]/Max[Abs[array]]], z > 0}}];

ListDensityPlot[array,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0,
 ColorFunction -> mycf,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Notice the predominance of *green* elements, as expected with the (biased) function.

The color function is defined differently for each data set (e.g., `array`).  How do I incorporate the maximum extent of the data so that it is set within the plotting function itself?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `"RedGreenSplit"` to be gray in the middle is not overly difficult; this can be done by combining `ColorData[]` with `Blend[]`, and then using a very thin bell curve (any will do, but I'll use a Cauchy one for this example) to control the blending:

```
(* the 400 can be replaced with an arbitrary large constant *)
rgg = Blend[{ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][#], Gray}, 1/(1 + 400 (# - 1/2)^2)] &;

LinearGradientImage[rgg, {600, 60}]
```

[image: preview of the gradient]

---

For the second part, where gray has to be pegged to zero, I have previously suggested in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182613) (as well as other ones) to use something like `LogisticSigmoid[]`:

```
(* kglr's sample data *)
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1];
            array1 = RandomReal[{-.5, 1}, {11, 11}];
            array2 = -array1];

ListDensityPlot[array1, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
                ColorFunction -> (rgg[LogisticSigmoid[10 #]] &), 
                ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: ListDensityPlot with adjusted color function]

```
ListDensityPlot[array2, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
                ColorFunction -> (rgg[LogisticSigmoid[10 #]] &), 
                ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: ListDensityPlot with adjusted color function]